# Has there been any research on plasma-producing planes?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

Many years ago I read in an expository scientific journal<sup>[1]</sup> an article about what the future of high speed aviation could be. It said that there were studies on airplanes capable of "plasma-izing" the air in front of them to get better lift and better aerodynamics.

Did they dream this up? Was there real research and, if so, did anything come out of it?

I've tried searching online, but the only things I've found are a bit too technical for me. From what I've been able to understand they are about using plasma generation in place of the control surfaces thus reducing vortices on wings.

<sub>[1] (one of those publications aimed at the divulgation of science to everyday people, not just for scientists)</sub>

Comment: I rejected the edit to the title because the suggested title was about planes replacing their control surfaces with plasma, that is **exactly what this question is not about**, as clearly explained in the question itself.

Comment: +1 For "divulgative." Didn't know that was even a word. Was going to change it to the more common "expository," but I liked it, so I left it :)

Comment: Would you possibly be able to find the article? You may be talking about [Electrohydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrohydrodynamics) in relation to [Ionocraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionocraft) which is a broad topic. A lot of aviation research was done in the 60's and 70's and there were many dead end research projects that never actually worked but info was published about their findings none the less.

Comment: [Or are you talking about this?](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/space/plasma-air-control/)

Comment: @Dave that's exactly one of the articles I found myself and that looks fully focused on control surfaces, that as I wrote in the question has nothing to do with what I'm searching for. I can't find the original article I because it was ages ago and that journal have been long lost

Comment: @motoDrizzt ok, you may want to try and find something at least along the lines of what you are looking for which will greatly help those on this site to answer your question. From an aviation standpoint this question is very broad with out a reference. Post what you have found that is too technical and we may be able to help make sense of it.

Comment: I went ahead and submitted an edit changing "divulgative" to "expository". I haven't found it in any dictionaries, which means that regardless of how much of a "valid" word it is, people are going to have trouble figuring out what it means.

Comment: @TannerSwett Party pooper. I was itching to use it on Scrabble! :)

Comment: I have been long wondering this exact same thing. I saw some research that claimed electrifying/plasmifying the air on the leading edge of a wing resulted in insane increase in lift and reduction of drag. But that was years ago and I haven't heard anything since.

Comment: Here is a demo showing how a plasma actuator changes the airflow on a wind turbine. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVJjn1pt08g